# I gave the authorization to www-data, how can I get it back

Tags: linux, permissions

I changed the authority of the `/etc` folder. How can I change it back to root?

The error I get when I want to switch to the root account:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 33, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Question may be appropriate for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.